# exception 'Bad variable type' when transfer data from query to excel

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4.2

This is code for exporting query data to excel. This assignment operator

> Range.Value := arrData;

causes exception:

> project raised exception class EOleSysError 'Bad variable type'

What may be the reason?

Units excel2000, ComObj are included.
Thanks in advance.

```
procedure Tform1.BExcelClick(Sender: TObject);
  var 
   row,col,i,j:integer;
   xls, wb, Range: OLEVariant;
   arrData: OleVariant;
begin
 Query1.Close;
 Query1.Open;
                
 row := Query1.RecordCount;
 col := Query1.FieldCount;
 arrData := VarArrayCreate([1, row, 1, col], varVariant);
                   
 i:=1;
 while not query1.Eof do begin
  for j:=1 to col do
    arrData[i,j] := query1.Fields[j-1].Value;
    query1.Next;
    Inc(i);
  end;
                                                                             
//or tried this   
{for i:=1 to row do begin                     
  for j:=1 to col do
    arrData[i,j] := Query1.Fields[j-1].Value;
     Query1.Next;
  end;
 }
           
 xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');                                  
 wb := xls.Workbooks.Add;     
              
 for j:=1 to col do
     WB.Worksheets[1].Cells[1,j]:= dbgrid1.Columns[j-1].Title.Caption;
                
 Range := wb.WorkSheets[1].Range[wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[2, 1], wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[row+1, col]];
 Range.Value := arrData;
 xls.Visible := True;
end;
```

**Update:** I find out what causes exception: query contains 2 fields- datetime field ("ExpDate") and и calculated field "summa" (quantity*price). Without them data correctly transferred in excel. If I include them in FDQuery exception occurs.
Query:

```
select 
 g.GoodsName,   --goods name 
 s.qnt,         --quantity of sold good
 s.Price,       -- price
 s.rg*s.price  as summa,       --(exception)
 i.ExpDate,   --expDate        --(exception)   
 t.temp       --store temperature
from goods g,sales s,  incomes i, temperatures t
where     (s.Doc_id=:Doc_id) and
          (s.goods_id= g.goods_id)and
          (s.record_id=i.record_id)and
          (g.temp_id=t.id)
group by g.goodsname, s.qnt, s.Price, summa, s.ExpDate, t.temp
order by g.GoodsName
```

How fix it?

**Solution:**

In for loop I change  operator

> arrData[i,j] := Query1.Fields[j-1].Value;

with

> arrData[i,j] := OleVariant(Query1.Fields[j-1].Value));

Comment: `WB.Worksheets.Application.Cells` makes absolutely no sense. You have a workbook, that has a worksheet that has cells. `Application` has no business in that line. Also, we have no idea what you're putting in that array from your query, so how are we supposed to know if there's a bad type in there or not? You've told us nothing about the array contents. When asking a question here, remember that we know **absolutely nothing** except what you include in your post - we can't see your screen or read your mind to get any missing information.

Comment: Also, I gave you **working code** in the link I provided to your previous question, but you've hacked it up into some sort of unreadable mess here. Why did you change it so drastically? All you needed to do was replace the data reference in my code to the one in your code and pretty much leave the rest alone.

Comment: @KenWhite you are right. I delete  WB.Worksheets.Application.Cells operator but that has nothing to do with my problem, nothing changed.  As for my query datas: there are 8  integer, float , string fields in db table. I changed it with sample integer value '1' but nothing changed.  As for you code I left main principle the same. There were error in it: dataset1.Fields[j-1, i-1].Value  and I correct it for query with query.Fields[[j-1]. . Also I remove bookmarks, disable/EnableControl and other minor things. The rest is the same.

Comment: There was one typo in my code (fixed-thanks), but you changed far more than that in your code. I used a `while` loop and a counter to keep track of the number of rows read from the database, and then used that when setting up the `Range`. I suspect that's where your problem is - you've given the wrong size to the `Range`, and there's not enough data in the array to fill that range like your code says it will.  There's a reason I used that `while` loop in my code.

Comment: @KenWhite I changed code: for i:=1 to row do begin
  for j:=1 to col do
    arrData[i,j] := Query1.Fields[j-1].Value;
     Query1.Next;
 end;   WITH  i:=0; while not query1.eof do begin
  for j:=1 to col do
    arrData[i,j] := Query1.Fields[j-1].Value;
     Query1.Next; Inc(i);
 end;     but the same error occurs.

Comment: That's twice you've posted a jumbled mess of code into comments and expected me to wade through it trying to figure out what you changed. It's not possible. Instead, [edit] your post, add a sentence that says *I also tried changing my code to* and post the code so that it can be formatted and is readable.

Comment: @KenWhite I edit post.

Comment: And yet you didn't fix the `row+1` when creating the range. I asked you to go back to look at my code (again) and told you what to look at, and you still didn't do as asked. This is really getting frustrating.

Comment: @KenWhite As you see,  first row is populated with titles of grid's columns. Range starts from the second row and therefore I write [row+1} for address of last cell.  For example, if dinamic array size is  5*8 and it begins from row 2 then address of first cell will be [2,1] and address of last cell will be  [row+1, col], in my case [6,8]. If I'm wrong correct me.

Comment: I find out what causes exception: query contains 2 fields-  datetime field and  и calculated field (quantity*price).  Without them data correctly transferred in excel. If I include them in FDQuery exception occurs. 
I edited post and add sql query in it.